# Worklight throuws ORA-12516 Intermittently

Tags: oracle, tomcat, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using Worklight 6.0 , Oracle 11.2.0.3. we are using Tomcat server 7.0.42
we are using ojdbc6.jar file

We are receiving the below error intermittently

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct'
>        defined in URL [jar:file:/u01/apps/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]:
>
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>       ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack

We ensured that in tomcat context.xml file the abandoned database connections are removed after the connections go idle for 60 seconds by having `removeAbandoned` as "true" and `removeAbandonedTimeout` as 60"

For your information the value of `PROCESSES` in Oracle DB is set to "1000"

Could you please let me know why we are getting the `ORA-12516` error intermittently , to unlock we are bouncing the DB. 
Are we missing something in Worklight Configurations that would allow the DB connections to be closed. What could be the root cause.

Comment: Next time this happens see how many processes are running: `select count(*) from v$process;`.  1000 is a very high number, but it's not that unusual for some process to incorrectly use many thousands of sessions.

Comment: thanks jonearles, will check

Comment: Idan, the issue has not turned up again after bouncing the DB last time. Will run the query select count(*) from v$process; once the issue occurs again

Comment: @Shireesh, any news? if all is Ok can you write an Answer?

Comment: @Idan, the issue did not occur again.

Comment: @Shireesh, Thanks. Please write what you did as an Answer.

Comment: The issue has not occurred once we bounced the DB. I have not replied till now as this not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has not occurred once the user bounced the DB. So bounce the DB.